# How can I find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\cfrac{1^p+2^p+\cdots+ n^p}{n^p}-\cfrac{n}{p+1}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Please help me to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\cfrac{1^p+2^p+\cdots +n^p}{n^p}-\cfrac{n}{p+1}\right),$$
where $p\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You can find this limit explicitely for $p=1,\,2,\,3$. Can you now make a guess for general $p$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula.

Comment: Hint: Actually it looks like an integral sum.

Comment: See my comment above. How many times are we going to see this same question again ?... There is a chain of duplicates

Answer (score 2):

By the trapezoidal method
$$
\frac1n\left(\tfrac12f(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(\tfrac{k}{n})+\tfrac12f(1)\right)=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+O(\tfrac1{n^2}).
$$
For $f(x)=x^p$ we get
$$
\frac1{n^{p+1}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^p - \tfrac12 n^p\right)=\frac{1}{p+1}+O(n^{-2})
$$
and in the form of the task
$$
\frac{1^p+2^p+…+n^p}{n^p}-\frac{n}{p+1}=\frac12 + O(n^{-1})
$$